# RabbitMQ in Java using Protobuf. Parse received data

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, protocol-buffers, spring-amqp

I am currently using springAMQP to communicate between java and my RabbitMQ node.
I am sending Protobuf data.

I would like to convert/cast/parse the received Message into the respective ProtoClass.

Here is the snippet from my Converter:

```
@Override
protected Message createMessage(Object object, MessageProperties messageProperties) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(object, "Object to send is null !");

    if (!com.google.protobuf.Message.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
        throw new MessageConversionException("Message wasn't a protobuf");
    } else {
        com.google.protobuf.Message protobuf = (com.google.protobuf.Message) object;
        byte[] byteArray = protobuf.toByteArray();

        messageProperties.setContentLength(byteArray.length);
        messageProperties.setContentType(ProtobufMessageConverter.CONTENT_TYPE_PROTOBUF);
        messageProperties.setHeader(ProtobufMessageConverter.MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME, protobuf.getDescriptorForType().getName());

        return new Message(byteArray, messageProperties);
    }
}

@Override
public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws MessageConversionException {

    com.google.protobuf.Message parsedMessage = null;
    try {
        if(ProtobufMessageConverter.CONTENT_TYPE_PROTOBUF.equals(message.getMessageProperties().getContentType())) {
            String typeName = getMessageTypeName(message);
            Descriptors.Descriptor messageType = fileDescriptor.findMessageTypeByName(typeName);
            parsedMessage = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(messageType, message.getBody());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Cannot convert, unknown message type %s".format(getMessageTypeName(message)));
    }
    return parsedMessage;
}
```

What do I have to do to be able to build the object?

Here is my proto file:

```
message queueReply {
    required string identifier = 1; cycle
    required uint32 keyId = 2;
    required bool success = 3; 
    required bytes result = 4; 
}
```

I would like to obtain the class queueReply from template.receiveAndConvert()

Comment: Do you have the full code somewhere? I'm trying to integrate this with Spring Boot but it is not working yet.

Comment: i might still have a copy somewhere. not open source though.

Comment: I have the code (id is public on github somewhere) but it does not get called. Do you have some code for receiving protobuf messages? I'm talking about the `MessageListener` here.

Comment: think i was using the amqptemplate in SpringAMQP

Comment: And where does `fileDescriptor` come from in your code?

Comment: that is the protobuf file descrptor https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FileDescriptor

Comment: I know its type but there is no reference to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
DynamicMessage o = (DynamicMessage)template.receiveAndConvert("queueName");
ProtoObject request = ProtoObject.parseFrom(o.toByteArray());
```